# How do you use the plastic cover/case that came with Arduino?

Tags: arduino-uno, shields, hardware

[image]They have holes for screw on, on top of the holes on the Arduino itself. Where can I find parts that are compatible with this case/cover? What was the intended use of this case/cover? Thanks.

Comment: Looks like there are some taps on the sides, so it should just snap in. USB side at the top (in your image). (PS this case goes on the bottom of the UNO)

Comment: just match up the shape of the board to the shape of the case .... the shape is not completely rectangular

Comment: What is the point of matching it? I bought a stand from amazon and that just screws to the board itself. Same with the stand that came from the starter kit. I'm probably going to throw this away, if there is no use...

Comment: `What was the intended use of this case/cover?` .... this question is unclear .... only you can answer what you intend to use the cover for

Comment: I bought Arduino uno and it came with it... I guess they just don't want the wires that stick out touch metal, like laptop covers? they probably thought leaving the back side naked was a bad idea...

Answer (score 1):

The cover was developed for Arduinos with on-board Ethernet with POE and similar cover has the Ethernet shield with POE. POE - power over Ethernet is 48 V, so it is better to not to touch a soldering point with this voltage.

The arduino.org boards were sold with this cover. Some of them had on-board esp8266 and soldering points leading to esp8266 sensitive pins. Again, better not to touch.

I used the cover to attach the Arduino to a DIN rail over a DIN rail clip.